# Plot usuário por semana pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho um arquivo csv que básicamente segue abaixo, estou tentando separar número de iteração do usuário por semana e plotar um gráfico para cada user.

```
Hora    Nome completo
8/08/2017 19:00 Joao
8/08/2017 19:00 Joao
8/08/2017 19:00 Joao
8/08/2017 18:55 Lucas
8/08/2017 18:55 Joao
```

Consegui uma solução para organizar usuário por data ,só não consegui plotar ainda, meu código pra organizar

```
 `import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from datetime import datetime 
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np




log_df = pd.read_csv('logs.csv',delimiter=",")
log_df['Hora'] = pd.to_datetime(log_df['Hora'])
df = log_df['Hora']


lenght = len(df)
tupla = [None]*lenght
for i in range(lenght):
        m = df[i]
        b = m.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        tupla[i] = b

week = tupla
log_df['Hora'] = tupla
log_df.set_index(log_df['Hora'], inplace=True)



grouped2 = pd.DataFrame({'count' : log_df.groupby( [ "Hora", "Nome completo"] ).size()}).reset_index()
print(grouped2)
```

A saída fica assim

```
Hora    Nome completo   Count
8/08/2017  Joao          4

8/08/2017  Lucas         1
```

no caso agora eu gostaria de plotar um gráfico nome do usuario e o numero de acesso para cada semana.
Minha duvida é como eu coloco ou separo por semana do ano agr?

Comment: Dá para mostrar o codigo que vc tentou?

Comment: Comentei o código mas não estou conseguindo plotar no eixo x o numero de semanas no eixo y quantidade de acesso por semana daquele usuario

Comment: Na minha opinião vc deveria editar a pergunta e incorporar a sua "resposta" a ela. Do jeito que está ficou um pouco confuso, a resposta é uma resposta ou uma nova pergunta? :-)

Comment: tentei explicar melhor...obrigado pela dica